# MVC3 AntiForgeryToken related issue, deep in the framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

I am running MVC3 web application on .Net 4 and IIS6 (Win2003 server). Intermittently we can capture following error messages:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string.
Parameter name: serializedToken
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryWorker.GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie(HttpContextBase httpContext, String salt, String domain, String path)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryWorker.GetHtml(HttpContextBase httpContext, String salt, String domain, String path)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml(HttpContextBase httpContext, String salt, String domain, String path)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken(String salt, String domain, String path)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()
   at ASP._Page_Views_Introduction_GetStarted_cshtml.Execute() in d:\MyProject\Views\ControllerName\ViewName.cshtml:line 43
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

In the view we have code

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        ... other codes ...
    }
```

And the receiving action method looks like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        // other logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Something", "Something");
    }
```

I think the coding should be right. Anybody ever experienced similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception after I wrote some cookie clearing code that nulled cookies instead of deleting them. AntiForgeryToken() seems to fail (even on a GET request) when the **RequestVerificationToken** cookie is blank.

Comment: But have you checked what cookies are sent using Firebug? What does the __ RequestVerificationTokenxxxx__ cookie look like? It may have been altered by another application on the same domain since the cookies don't specify a path by default they are shared between different apps on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all your cookies from the browser. Try the browser in incognito mode also or different browser also. 
I had same problem. Not touching cookies and this happened. It apeared that problem was caused by doing system restore in combination with windows password change. Insane..